# Why do I get syntax error for "INSERT INTO"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

```
String pName = getStrFromUser("Product name: ");
int price = getIntFromUser("Price: ", false);
String category = getStrFromUser("Category: ");
String description = getStrFromUser("Description: ");

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ws.products (name, price, cid, description) VALUES (?, ?, (SELECT ws.categories.cid FROM ws.categories WHERE ws.categories.name LIKE ?), ?)");

statement.setString(1, pName);
statement.setInt(2, price);
statement.setString(3, category);
statement.setString(4, description);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

I get:

```
Error encountered: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT INTO ws
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: can you share the full stacktrace please

Comment: which RDBS You are using?

Comment: It only prints "Error encountered: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT INTO ws"
  Position: 1"

Comment: I am assuming its near like as the syntax for like is `Like '   '`.. It needs to have quotes

Comment: I use PostgreSQL

Comment: table name needs to be like this: \`ws.products\` (single quoted)

Comment: there are many piece in your question not shown, can you please share how you declare your connection how your table is created?

Comment: The above INSERT syntax is fine. Is it really exactly the same as you execute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subquery inside the `VALUES` clause looks suspicious.  Try rephrasing as an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ws.products (name, price, cid, description) ";
sql += "SELECT ?, ?, cid, ? FROM ws.categories WHERE name LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setString(1, pName);
statement.setInt(2, price);
statement.setString(3, description);
statement.setString(4, category);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO ws.products (name, price, cid, description) 
    SELECT ?, ?, ws.categories.cid, ?
    FROM ws.categories
    WHERE ws.categories.name LIKE ?;
```

This will not fix the problem with `INSERT`, but it will prevent the *next* problem of a subquery returning more than one row.

My best guess for that problem is that the library you are using only supports `SELECT` statements.  That would be atypical; `INSERT` is usually allowed.